# Text Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, css

I know this incorrect but I would like to know how to implement a type of validation so when the input is correct the background goes green or if it's incorrect goes red let's use the email example. http://jsfiddle.net/dm6Hm/20/

```html
<input type="email" class="Email" value="Email"/>
```

```js
(".Email").change(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if ($test.val() == "email@email.com") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "green").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: onblur event should work,try replacing it with change!!!

Comment: I am confused, I am trying to validate the input style using javascript.

Comment: check the answer,it may work..let me know if you need that in javascript!!!

Comment: I guess you need to change the border color of text box,nor the background color?

Comment: All it's doing right now is simply setting the background to green it isn't validating any actual input, I would like for it to turn green or red depending on type of input (if it's correct or incorrect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isEmail(email){
    var reg = /^(\w)+(\.\w+)*@(\w)+((\.\w+)+)$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}

$(".Email").keyup(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if (isEmail($test.val())) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "green").focus();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for correct input-->

   $('.Email').focus(function() {
        $('.Email').css('border','1px solid green');
    });

for incorrect input:

 $('.Email').blur(function() {
        $('.Email').css('border','1px solid red');
    });
```

You need to change your events

Comment: Yes but it's not validating the input try uploading a jsfiddle to show me what you mean.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement that part.

Comment: @JohnSmith:try do a little searching before you post question.From your question it appears that you are struggling with changing color,but now when you said you struggling with the validation part...i realised that your problem is something else.
The above example has the kind of validation that you are looking for.Is that what you want or something else?

Comment: I am sorry messiah, I really am but you've given me the help I needed, you both have I got the solution from 4chan check it out - http://jsfiddle.net/dm6Hm/21/

Comment: don't worry you've actually solved the answer properly, don't goto 4chan it's a disgusting place where you will lose your mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".Email").keyup(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if ($test.val() === "email@email.com") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "green").focus();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is really good but I need it to actually validate the input so email@email.com was an example, I am trying to make it work for real emails.

Comment: Strangely enough someone from 4chan answered the question, thanks guys I really appreciate the effort you had taken to help me!

Comment: Added it. You can check it.